# Salesforce Picklist value to hide --None-- in lightning version

Tags: lightning, picklist

Salesforce Picklist value to hide --None-- in lightning version:

For the same issue, there is a solution that making the field as mandatory on the pagelayout and defaulting any one picklist value will remove --None--, but this works only for Classic version not for Lightning version.

Now i need to remove --None-- picklist value for Lightning version, Please let know for any solution.

Comment: I would expect marking it as mandatory in the layout would resolve this in a lightning record page. Are you seeing this in the lightning record page using the "Record Detail" standard component or is this in some custom LWC?

Answer (score 1):

--None-- is disabled in classic when we make field mandatory on the layout and this will not work in lightning. Kindly review Idea [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BqEeAAK) and vote for this feature.

Thanks,